# Generating a random number in ARM assembly with Raspberry Pi

Tags: assembly, random, arm, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on an assembly project right now and I have to generate a random number. So far I've managed to write some code that should work, but I don't think is working beacuse it does not print the random number. My code is this:

```
/*--random01.s*/
.data

.balign 4
mensaje1: .asciz "Random \n"

.balign 4
return: .word 0

.text

.global main
main:

    ldr r1, addr_of_return
    str lr, [r1]

    ldr r0, addr_of_msg1
    bl printf

    tst r1,r1, lsr #1
    movs r2,r0, rrx
    adc r1,r1, r1
    eor r2,r2, r0, lsl #12
    eor r0,r2, r2, lsr #20

    ldr r0, [r0]
    bl printf

    ldr lr, addr_of_return
    ldr lr, [lr]
    bx lr

addr_of_msg1: .word mensaje1
addr_of_return: .word return

.global printf
```

My question is, how can I achieve the generation of a random number? Am I doing this right or should I try working with the clock?

Comment: No this is a terrible random number generator. The value that R0 starts with is the return value of `printf`, a number that never changes. The TST and ADC instructions do nothing. The MOVS instruction shifts in the carry flag, which is whatever `printf` set it to, and so is likely always going to be the same. So your initial seed is essentially the return value of printf. The EOR instructions look like an incomplete xorshift implementation.  Then you do `ldr r0, [r0]` which reads a "random", but always the same, memory location and probably crashes.

Comment: _"it does not print the random number"_ - well, why would it? Beyond all the things Ross points out, there's no format string for the second call to `printf`.

Comment: You should open up `/dev/urandom` and read some bytes.

Comment: Oh! Ok ok thanks guys (I'm new to this). I really appreciate your answers, I'm going to fix up the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some notifications to your program to get it to print if you wish to try more options.

```
/*--random01.s*/
.data

.balign 4
mensaje1: .asciz "Random \n"

@ ---- Added ----
.balign 4
format: .asciz "%d \n"
@ ---------------

.balign 4
return: .word 0

.text

.global main
main:

    ldr r1, addr_of_return
    str lr, [r1]

    ldr r0, addr_of_msg1
    bl printf

    tst r1,r1, lsr #1
    movs r2,r0, rrx
    adc r1,r1, r1
    eor r2,r2, r0, lsl #12
    eor r0,r2, r2, lsr #20

@ ---- Added ----
    mov r1, r0              @ num goes to r1
    ldr r0, addr_of_format  @ format to r0
@ ---------------

@   ldr r0, [r0]
    bl printf

    ldr lr, addr_of_return
    ldr lr, [lr]
    bx lr

addr_of_msg1: .word mensaje1
addr_of_return: .word return
@ ---- Added ----
addr_of_format: .word format
@ ---------------
.global printf
```

Here is a program that reads one byte from /dev/urandom and prints it to stdout. The number is 0 to 255 (one of those numbers or between them). Some reference is http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~swanson/papers/Oakland2013EarlyEntropy.pdf. I did not understand most of it.

```
@----------------------------------

.data

@ See /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/asm/unistd.h
@ See /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/fcntl-linux.h

    .equ create,     8
         .equ Mode, 0644       @ -rw-r--r--
    .equ open,       5
         .equ Rd,   00
         .equ Wr,   01
         .equ RdWr, 02
         .equ Apnd, 02000
    .equ read,       3
    .equ write,      4
    .equ close,      6
    .equ sync,       36
    .equ exit,       1
    .equ sfile,      187

@----------------------------------

.balign 4
dir_file:
    .asciz "/dev/urandom"

.balign 4
Open:
    .word dir_file, RdWr | Apnd, open

.balign 4
Buf:
    .word 0 

.balign 4
Read:
    .word Buf, 1, read

.balign 4
format:
    .asciz "%3d\n"

@----------------------------------

.text

.global main, printf

main:

     push   {r4, r5, r7, lr}     @ folowing AAPCS

     ldr    r3, =Open            @ load address
     ldm    r3, {r0, r1, r7}     @ load registers
     svc    #0                   @ OS opens file
     mov    r4, r0               @ save fd in r4

     ldr    r3, =Read            @ load address
     ldm    r3, {r1, r2, r7}     @ load registers
     svc    #0                   @ OS reads file

     mov    r0, r4               @ move fd in r0
     mov    r7, #close           @ num for close
     svc    #0                   @ OS closes file

     ldr    r0, =format          @ adress of format
     ldr    r1, =Buf             @ addr of byte red
     ldr    r1, [r1]             @ load byte
     bl     printf               @ C() print byte
     mov    r0, #0               @ 0 = success

exit:

     pop    {r4, r5, r7, lr}     @ folowing AAPCS
     bx     lr                   @ Exit if use gcc as linker
```

NOTE:
as to assemble, gcc to link, tested on RPi3

Comment: You can also use GCC to both assemble and link in one go.